# Windows logo loading, can't turn on my PC

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to turn on my PC but when I'm doing that, *the Windows logo keeps loading* and I can't pass through it.

I've tried different things to fix it:

- While turning on, I've open *the automatic recovery mode* but it doesn't work.
- I've also tried to activate *the safe mode* but it doesn't work too.

Here what I have when I'm trying to turn on my PC:

[image: Here is my screen]

My next step is going to remove dust from it but I prefer to post an issue before.

Thanks.

Comment: Removing dust won’t solve Windows being unable to boot from a seal storage device.  This is a storage problem, the drive likely failed, which is the reason the automatic repair isn’t resolving the problem

Comment: Now, I'm trying to boot Windows with a USB key. @Ramhound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to boot my PC with a USB key with the latest version of Windows and it works.

I've activate the boot menu with F12 (Toshiba brand PC) and then boot my PC on the USB key.

I've back up the old version and install the new one.